# Warning message: In method$prob(modelFit =modelFit, newdata =newdata, submodels =param) : kernlab class probability calculations failed; returning NAs

Tags: r, svm, caret

I'm getting the following error above which seems to be related to the caret package.  I have checked my data and don't have any NA values as they were all removed in the cleaning stages.
I'm trying to get the probabilities for the AUC to compare against the other ML algorithms I'm using in my project. My code is as follows:

```
    Cost = 2^c(1:8)

    svm.control = trainControl(
    method = "cv", # use cross validation
    number = 10, # with 10 folds,
    summaryFunction = defaultSummary,
    #classProbs = TRUE
    )


   svm.linear.grid <- expand.grid(
         C = Cost
   )


   svm.fit1 <- train( # Train a model model
       final_result ~ ., 
       data = sd.BBB.train.rose, # sd.BBB.train.rose as the training data
       method = "svmLinear", # using the linear kernel
       trControl = svm.control, # cross-validated as configured above
       preProc = c("center", "scale","nzv"), 
       verbose = FALSE,
       #metric="ROC",
       tuneGrid = svm.linear.grid # use the tuning grid created above
   )

   #roc and auc analysis 
   svm.prob <- predict(svm.fit2, newdata = sd.BBB.test[,-8], type="prob")
```

The strsuture of my dataset is

```
  > str(sd.BBB.train.rose)
  'data.frame': 4926 obs. of  8 variables:
  $ gender              : num  0.0713 -0.0131 0.0321 -0.0881 -0.0344 ...
  $ highest_education   : num  0.0761 0.6618 0.2545 1.275 -0.2358 ...
  $ age_group           : num  -0.1609 0.023 0.0563 0.103 -0.2153 ...
  $ previous_attempts   : num  -0.0689 0.8812 -0.2724 0.9355 0.9366 ...
  $ disability          : num  -0.0664 0.2857 -0.0461 1.0651 -0.0573 ...
  $ avg_clicks          : num  0.588 4.666 4.174 3.228 3.532 ...
  $ academic_performance: num  3.95 1.39 3.51 -1.84 4.31 ...
  $ final_result        : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 >
```

Any help greatly appreciated. Respectfully.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite difficult to be sure without having the data available to reproduce your error, but I think if you want to get the probabilities returned, you have to specify `classProbs =  TRUE` in the `train` function. Try this:

```
svm.fit1 <- train( # Train a model model
       final_result ~ ., 
       data = sd.BBB.train.rose, # sd.BBB.train.rose as the training data
       method = "svmLinear", # using the linear kernel
       trControl = svm.control, # cross-validated as configured above
       preProc = c("center", "scale","nzv"), 
       verbose = FALSE,
       #metric="ROC",
       tuneGrid = svm.linear.grid, # use the tuning grid created above
       classProbs = TRUE
   )
```